# React native email sending

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gmail-api, nodemailer

I was hoping to add a page in my RN app where users can report a bug by filling out a form which would send an email with the info straight to my inbox. I looked online and found nodemailer as an option but found it very confusing to use with react native, does anybody have any resources that could help (nodemailer rn app github examples or videos) or alternatives? (Doesn't necessarily have to be email based as long as I can retrieve the bug info filled out by the user in the form)

Answer (score 0):

Good day, have you looked at [this](https://github.com/tiaanduplessis/react-native-email)? Essentially you would create your `formComponent` and pass those fields to `email` function in this module.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution where I could stay in the app instead of being linked to the native mail app instead, something where when the user presses submit, they are sent back to the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail) wrapper to send email in both Android and iOS.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution where I could stay in the app instead of being linked to the native mail app instead, something where when the user presses submit, they are sent back to the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working well [react-native-smtp-mailer](https://github.com/angelos3lex/react-native-smtp-mailer), but has some attachments problem on Android. If you do not need to send attachments it's simple solution.

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless